# Understanding Node.js processing order

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having problems understanding the processing order in Node.js.
My Problem:
I coded a little Application that saves a session in a cookie with the following properties:

```
session.email = email;
session.randomHash = randomHash;
```

The randomHash var is a random String that gets generated and saved to a db everytime the user logs in.
If a user with a session now wants to view a private page the method checkSession() gets called:

```
exports.checkSession = function(req, res) {
    if(req.session) {
        var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
        User.count({email: req.session.email, randomHash: req.session.randomHash}, function(err, count) {
            if(count === 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if(count === 1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

The method compares the randomHash of the cookie with the randomHash value of the Db.
This method is called in a route:

```
exports.init = function(req, res) {
    if(hashing.checkSession(req, res)) {
        res.render("controlpanel", {title: "Controlpanel", email: req.session.email});
    }
    else {
        res.send("Sorry but you are not logged in. Go to /login");
    }   
};
```

Now there must be the problem.
Because of Nodes non-blocking style the method gets called but doesn't finish before the if-statement is executed.
What can i do about it?

Comment: Welcome to the callback hell !

Comment: callbacks are hardly 'hell'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` value in your `User.count` callback is not the `return` value of `checkSession`. The `User.count` callback doesn't run until *after* `checkSession` has finished.

Pass a callback to `checkSession` and call it in `User.count`:

```
exports.checkSession = function(req, res, callback) {
    if(req.session) {
        var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
        User.count({email: req.session.email, randomHash: req.session.randomHash}, function(err, count) {
            if(count === 0) {
                callback(false);
            }
            if(count === 1) {
                callback(true);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        callback(false);
    }
};
```

And call it like:

```
exports.init = function(req, res) {
    hashing.checkSession(req, res, function(result) {
        if(result) {
            res.render("controlpanel", {title: "Controlpanel", email: req.session.email});
        }
        else {
            res.send("Sorry but you are not logged in. Go to /login");
        }
    });
};
```